# My Google add-on script is no longer recognizing me as the owner

Tags: add-on, ownership

I don't believe there's any way to contact a human being at Google to help with this, unfortunately.

I have an add-on that I developed years ago: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/doc-variables/ggigadkkljhdchdhpliohdcokbnpcnjn?hl=en

In the last few weeks (last publish 5/29/17) I can no longer publish from the script editor.  It says, "Only the owner of a script can publish the script as an add-on.".

I know I own the app/script:[dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qirFs.jpg)

One item to mention is that our organization (the account associated with it) recently changed our domain.  Is it possible this disconnected my ownership some how?  Anyone have any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that you own the webstore item but not that you own the script itself.

If it's a standalone script, then make sure you also own the script document in Google Drive. Perhaps, the ownership has been changed or you've opened Script Editor with a different account. If the ownership has been changed and you cannot change it back, you can make a copy of the script that you'll own.

Comment: Thank you for the response... I do own the script document and I have gone into the API console to make sure the IAM settings are correct: https://imgur.com/a/jkJ6i

I wish I could find out who it THINKS owns the script.  Up until June I had no problem publishing.